# Adobe Flex center label over image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to center a label over an image, but its not working, it stays at the top left corner....please help:

```
<mx:Canvas>

        <mx:Image id="img" showEffect="Fade" completeEffect="{fader}" />

        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">

            <mx:Label id="touchBegin" text="Touch the screen to continue" fontSize="72" />

        </s:HGroup>

    </mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have IDE opened, but I'm pretty sure that's because of the width of the `hgroup` does not match the one of an image, try:

`<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" width="{img.width}">`